# Get first 16 Bytes from Blob object decoded from Base64

Tags: integration, crypto

I have to call an external REST service and I have to decode the response.

From external service documentation I think I have to decode the response with AES algorithm in this way:

```
public static string decrypt(string encryptedText, string secretKey)
{
                blob encryptedData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encryptedText);
                blob iv = first 16 byte of encryptedData
                blob message = then 17 byte of encryptedData
                blob decryptedData= Crypto.decrypt('AES256', secretKey, iv, message);

                return decryptedData.toString();           
}
```

But I can't figure out how take the bytes from Blob object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the BlobSplitter apex class by [@MetaDaddy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) in the question [Mimic MySQL AES_ENCRYPT in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/910/102).

You can use [EncodingUtil.convertToHex()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) to get a hexadecimal (base 16) representation of the blob. So the first two characters in the hexadecimal string will represent the first byte of the encryptedData. To get the first 16 bytes you will need the first 32 hexadecimal characters.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but wouldn't the first 32 characters in the hexadecimal string represent the first 16 bytes of the encrypted data? Since two hexadecimal characters = one byte?

Comment: Whoops, good point. I've updated the answer with with the correct conversion.