# Encrypting and/or decrypting ciphertext with the provided Initialization Vector (IV)

Tags: apex, crypto

I had given an cipher text (of JSON string), an IV and a key. I tried decrypting using [Apex Crypto class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm)'s method:

> decryptWithManagedIV(algorithmName, privateKey, IVAndCipherText)

```
  //Sample code
  Blob key = Blob.valueOf(decryptionKey);
  Blob encryptedDatafor = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(bodystring);
  Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptwithManagedIV('AES128', key, encryptedDatafor);

  cipher = decryptedData.toString();
  System.debug('Encrypted BodyString: ' +cipher);
```

and I was able to decrypt the cipher successfully. But when I use the provided IV with the following method:

> decrypt(algorithmName, privateKey, initializationVector, cipherText)

```
 //Sample code
 Blob exampleIV = Blob.valueOf('HSDlUkhrmfEo7SgM'); //provided IV 
 Blob key = Blob.valueOf(decryptionKey);
 Blob encryptedDatafor = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(bodystring);
 Blob decryptedDataIV = Crypto.decrypt('AES128', key, exampleIV, encryptedDatafor);

 cipher = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(decryptedDataIV );
 System.debug('Encrypted BodyString: ' +cipher);
```

I get some string which looks like, it is still in the encrypted form (different from the encrypted string I have passed).

Update: 
I have tried the below code-snippet based on the suggestion from @identigral, but I am still unable to decrypt the cipher using the IV:

```
Blob exampleIV = Blob.valueOf('HSDlUkhrmfEo7SgM'); //provided IV 
Blob key = Blob.valueOf(decryptionKey);
Blob encryptedDatafor = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(bodystring);

String encodedCipherTextAndIV = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(encryptedDatafor);
String encodedCipherText = encodedCipherTextAndIV.substring(32);
String finCipher = encodedCipherText.difference(encodedCipherTextAndIV);
Blob ciphertext = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(finCipher); 

Blob decryptedDataIV = Crypto.decrypt('AES128', key, exampleIV, ciphertext);

decryptStg = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(decryptedDataIV );
System.debug('Decrypted BodyString: ' +decryptStg);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't decrypt the same ciphertext (`bodystring`) in your example with both `decryptWithManagedIV` and `decrypt` methods, only one of them will work. `decryptWithManagedIV` assumes that the ciphertext includes an initialization vector. If this is indeed the case, then `bodystring` consists of an IV (first 16 bytes), then the rest of it is actual stuff that was originally encrypted. Using `decrypt` on the same ciphertext will only work if you remove the IV from `bodystring`.

To remove the first 16 bytes from a binary Blob, you have to manipulate its hex representation. From [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/get-first-16-bytes-from-blob-object-decoded-from-base64):

> Use EncodingUtil.convertToHex() to get a hexadecimal (base 16)
>   representation of the blob. So the first two characters in the
>   hexadecimal string will represent the first byte of the encryptedData.
>   To get the first 16 bytes you will need the first 32 hexadecimal
>   characters.

Example with a complete roundtrip:

```
String text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over 13 lazy dogs.';
Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(text);
String b64Data = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);

Blob ciphertextAndIV = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);
Blob plaintext = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, ciphertextAndIV);
String b64Decrypted = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(plaintext);
System.debug('Text = plaintext: ' + (text == plaintext.toString()));
System.debug('Base64-text = Base64-plaintext: ' + (b64Decrypted == b64Data));

String encodedCiphertextAndIV = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(ciphertextAndIV);
String encodedCiphertext = encodedCiphertextAndIV.substring(32);
String encodedIV = encodedCiphertextAndIV.substring(0,32);
Blob ciphertext = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(encodedCiphertext);
Blob IV = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(encodedIV);
Blob plaintext2 = Crypto.decrypt('AES128', key, IV, ciphertext);
String b64Decrypted2 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(plaintext2);
System.debug('Text = plaintext: ' + (text == plaintext2.toString()));
System.debug('Base64-text = Base64-plaintext: ' + (b64Decrypted2 == b64Data));
```

Comment: That makes sense to me. But, how can I separate the first 16 bytes from the encrypted `body` string? Do I need to delete the first 16 characters from the `body`? If so, I did that too. And I get an error that says: `System.SecurityException: last block incomplete in decryption`. Any workaround?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. See updated answer

Comment: One quick question: Looks like your `ciphertext` is actually the IV bytes, right (first 16 bytes)? Correct me if I am wrong. I am guessing this as I am still getting some encrypted text.

Comment: I added a more complete example

Comment: Awesome. That works perfect. One little question: 
What does your `encodedCiphertext` convert too? Does it extract the substring after 32nd character, making it separate from the IV? I understood the string function you did for `IV`.

Comment: `encodedCiphertext` is the substring after the 32nd character, yes.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks for your pretty quick responses. If it's not for the Stackexchange's maintenance downtime, I could've got your responses even earlier.