# Use of the managed Ini Vector in the Apex Crypto Class

Tags: apex, encryption

I am wondering about when to use the managedIv method in the Apex crypto class. I noticed that if I use the managedIv method with a key from the Apex generateAESKey() method my results are always a little bit off.

As an example if I run the following in anonymous Apex it turns "Is this Working" into "Isthisworkin".

```
Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);

Blob testString = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('Is this working');

Blob result =  Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, testString );

System.debug(result);

Blob decryptedBlob = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, result);

System.debug(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(decryptedBlob));
```

But if run it with the Crypto.encrypt() and provide an IV with the same key it works. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271648/encrypting-and-or-decrypting-ciphertext-with-the-provided-initialization-vector for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the encoding that's at fault, not the crypto.

`Is this working` is not a Base64 string. In fact, if you take `testString` and try to decode it back to a string, you'll get an error because it doesn't produce valid UTF-8.

If you directly convert blobs to Strings, you'll get the right result:

```
Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);

Blob testString = Blob.valueOf('Is this working');

Blob result =  Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, testString );

System.debug(result);

Blob decryptedBlob = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, result);

System.debug(decryptedBlob.toString());
```

> 11:42:27:009 USER_DEBUG [11]|DEBUG|Is this working

The fact that it works with an explicit IV and not with a managed IV is not immediately clear to me - possibly the data is being padded differently somewhere such that it *accidentally* returns the right result? - but the root cause is definitely the use of Base64 where it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, David.